# Android Studio Build Signed App Manifest Error

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, android-manifest

I receive these errors when my signed build;

> Android resource linking failed Output: C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher (aka com.platesupp.car:drawable/ic_launcher) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.platesupp.car:string/app_name) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.platesupp.car:style/AppTheme) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: resource string/app_name (aka com.platesupp.car:string/app_name) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:62: error: resource string/title_activity_register (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_register) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:66: error: resource string/title_activity_login (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_login) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:70: error: resource string/title_activity_home (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_home) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:74: error: resource string/title_activity_tag (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_tag) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:78: error: resource string/title_activity_search (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_search) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:82: error: resource string/title_activity_chat (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_chat) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:86: error: resource string/title_activity_profile (aka com.platesupp.car:string/title_activity_profile) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:93: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.platesupp.car:style/AppTheme) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:98: error: resource array/preloaded_fonts (aka com.platesupp.car:array/preloaded_fonts) not found. C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml:183: error: resource integer/google_play_services_version (aka com.platesupp.car:integer/google_play_services_version) not found. error: failed processing manifest.
>
> Command: C:\Users\engin.ardic.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cf3854db92cef5eb88102ca698f23759\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link --proto-format\ -I\ C:\Users\engin.ardic\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar\ --manifest\ C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\processReleaseManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\ -o\ C:\Source\Repos\platesupp\platesUpp_android\Car1\car\build\intermediates\linked_res_for_bundle\release\bundleReleaseResources\bundled-res.ap_\ --auto-add-overlay\ -0\ apk\ --no-version-vectors Daemon: AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: Where do you have these resources defined? Are they in the 'main' source-set or the 'debug' one by any chance?

Comment: Looks like it could be a duplicate of https://issuetracker.google.com/117947859 - can you try upgrading our android gradle plugin version to  3.3.0-alpha11 or newer?